# Можно ли на ПК установить отдельный ярлык на рабочий для гугл-диска или гмаил-почты?

Tags: windows, bat

Чтобы к определенному браузеру этот гугл-диск был подвязан. К слову, у меня 10 браузеров. Занимаюсь веб-разработкой. Каждый браузер - для своих задач. И вот нужно для удобства, как на смартфоне есть отдельные ярлыки, вот так для Виндовс 10 такое решение можно реализовать. И еще один нюанс. Браузер по умолчанию у меня Comodo Dragon, но если входит из ярлыка с рабочего стола гугл-диск например, чтобы входил в гугл хром. Как можно реализовать такое? Буду рад любым решениям и подсказкам.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать стандартные возможности ярлыков и указать ключи для запуска программы, либо использовать bat-ники

[image: Скриншот свойств ярлыка]

Comment: Абсолютно правильный ответ. Создавайте необходимые Вам ярлыки для каждой из запускаемых программ. Поиск по словам "ключи запуска [название нужного браузера]"